# Center or square first when creating a quadratic term with a grand-mean centered variable in a multilevel model

Tags: quadratic-form

I have a standard 2-level hierarchical linear model that I’m doing (household water use is the dependent variable), and one of the level-1 (household-level) variables (average cost) includes a quadratic term. Put simply, I am unsure whether to center the quadratic term before or after I ‘square’ it. I have received conflicting answers about this from my advisor and committee members (as well as articles and internet posts), but am a bit concerned because the decision does produce tangible differences.

I’m leaning towards centering before squaring, as this seems to be the more common approach in the articles that I’ve been reading...

I’d really appreciate any insight that anyone might be able to offer on this!

Answer (score 1):

Should you center then square a covariate for a quadratic model, or square then center it? I haven't exhausted the topic here, and haven't thought of every possible situation, but here are some common situations and my understanding of them.

This is an old post, but I find myself asking this question and working back through it every so often, so I thought I'd put my notes down here.

EXAMPLE 1

First, let's consider a covariate with an all-positive distribution:

```
#EXAMPLE 1
#first, let's consider a covariate with an all-positive distribution
set.seed(34)
x=rnorm(100,mean=4,sd=1);hist(x)

#here is the relationship between x and x^2 for this variable
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(x,x^2,main="True relationship");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you square then scale/center
plot(scale(x),scale(x^2),main="Square then center");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you scale/center then square
#it doesn't match the other two
xb=scale(x)
plot(xb,xb^2,main="Center then square");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#conclusion: assuming you want the model to reflect the true relationship between x and x^2, you should square first and then center/scale
```

Conclusion: assuming you want the model to reflect the true relationship between x and x^2,
#you should *square first* and then *center/scale second* (see first figure):

[image: Example 1]

EXAMPLE 2

Now what about a covariate that has both negative and positive values (i.e. spans zero)?

```
#EXAMPLE 2
#now what about a covariate that has both negative and positive values (i.e. spans zero)? 
x=rnorm(100);hist(x)

#here is the 'true' relationship between x and x^2 for this variable
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(x,x^2,main="True relationship");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you square then scale/center
plot(scale(x),scale(x^2),main="Square then center");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you scale/center then square
xb=scale(x)
plot(xb,xb^2,main="Center then square");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#in this case it doesn't matter which method you choose in terms of the x to x^2 relationship
#but, note that if you scale first then square the quadratic term is (obviously) no longer centered
#so squaring before centering is probably better even here in most cases
```

So squaring *before* centering is probably better even here in most cases (see second figure):

[image: Example 2]

EXAMPLE 3

But, for a covariate that spans zero (e.g. Example 2), I would consider whether zero was a 'real' thing for that covariate for the purposes of your question. For example, for degrees Celsius, zero might be meaningful if you are e.g. modeling behavior of water molecules. But if you're modeling e.g. the probability of a given species occurring, then 'zero' probably doesn't have much 'real' meaning for this temperature covariate (which might be e.g. mean January temp).

```
#EXAMPLE 3
#But, for a covariate that spans zero (e.g. Example 2), I would consider whether zero was a 'real' thing for that covariate for the purposes of your question.
#For example, for degrees Celsius, zero might be meaningful if you are e.g. modeling behavior of water molecules. But if you're modeling e.g. 
#the probability of a given species occurring, then 'zero' probably doesn't have for this temperature covariate (which might be e.g. mean January temp).

#in that case, you are probably interested in the type of relationship between x and x^2 depicted in Example 1, rather than in Example 2,
#and the fact that your covariate spans zero is more of an artifact of the scale that is used rather than a 'real' property of the covariate
#in that case, you might want to a) shift the covariate to be all positive, b) square it, then c) center it as in Example 1:

#covariate that spans zero 'by accident', and you want the x to x^2 relationship to be as shown in Example 1
#so start with a similar X as in Example 2
x=rnorm(100);hist(x)

#shift it to all positive
xShift=x+abs(min(x))+sd(x) #adding some arbitrary value '+sd(x) so minimum value is above zero, but not by much relative to the span of X 
hist(xShift,main="x shifted to be positive
     (xShift)")

#so here are the 'original' and 'new' x to x^2 relationships
plot(x,x^2,main="Original relationship");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#now here is the new relationship between x and x^2 for this variable
plot(xShift,xShift^2,main="'Corrected' relationship
     xShift");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you square then scale/center
plot(scale(xShift),scale(xShift^2),main="Square then center
     xShift");abline(coef=c(0,1),lty=2)

#here is the same relationship if you scale/center then square
xShiftb=scale(xShift)
plot(xShiftb,xShiftb^2,lty=2,main="Center then square
     xShift");abline(coef=c(0,1))

#so, again, in this case you should square then center
```

So, again, in this case you should probably *square* then *center* (see third figure):

[image: Example 3]